# Cat threw up clear liquid?

Tags: cats, health

I have two kittens at home. One of them, not sure which one, seems to have thrown up twice over night. At first I only saw one puddle, and thought it's soft stool. But upon closer inspection, I'm pretty sure it was vomit, especially because it was somewhat "grainy" and smelled kind of neutral. I later discovered a second puddle, but it was completely clear. I searched some pictures on google, but all "clear" puddles seem to either be yellow-ish or foamy. What I found was really transparent/clear, almost like water. As I'm a new cat owner, I'm honestly not really sure. Is it possible the second puddle is actually pee? My cats never peed on the floor (thank God), so I'm not sure what it would smell like. It smelled slightly acidic, so I thought it might be stomach fluid?

As I said, I don't know which of the cats had to vomit, but they're both behaving normally, so I'm assuming as long as there is no more vomiting, I don't need to be alarmed?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

It’s hard to say exactly what you’re seeing since you didn’t witness the cat making the mess. A kitten may have had an accident, but pee is typically yellow, and you would have noticed a scent. I always wipe up messes with a white paper towel to pick up on any colors I’m seeing.

A clear/foamy liquid being thrown up isn’t necessarily cause for concern either, but do keep a close eye on your kittens over the next day to watch for other symptoms.

I have witnessed cats throwing up clear/foamy liquid quite a few times. Typically, it’s if they gag on something (either eating too fast or trying to swallow something they can’t), but without enough of it to cause them to fully empty their stomach contents. Basically stomach acid and spit, much like if you were to dry heave. This doesn’t hurt the cat, but is a signal for you to watch what they eat or try to eat. Make sure they’re not chewing on anything toxic, eating too fast, or trying to swallow toys.

Answer (score -1):

I’ve had that issue before
It may be gastritis but it’s not to worry about unless symptoms increase I’m sure it was stomach acid. I have a query abou the age
My kitten done it when he was 6 weeks possibly as he ate something toxic